# Is Writing Non-ORM Model Code in a ORM Model Class Acceptable?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am building a very small API using Python and was wondering whether it is generally acceptable to place API code in a model class when using frameworks like Django or Flask (with an ORM like Peewee or Pony). Let me explain what I mean...

To illustrate what I mean, imagine I have a package with all my models and then another package with my API code which executes when a client pings a particular route that I have defined. As you know, the models are basically only for mapping objects to the database. Although, under certain circumstances, it personally makes more sense for some reason to place some of the API code in one of the model classes I have defined.

For example, I have a User model that maps a user to the database. Additionally, in the API code, I have a function to login the user. This function basically sets the cookies to login the user so it might make sense to place it in the API package. However, I feel like if I make this function a method and place it in the user model, it makes more sense semantically and might be easier to understand.

```
class UserModel(Peewee or Pony or Django.model...):
    def login(self):
        """" Login code goes here. Set cookies, login the user, etc. """
        add_cookies(self.username)
        return jsonify({"logged_in": True})  # Flask example...

user = UserModel()
user.login()
```

One caveat of doing this, however, is that the models code and the API code are no longer decoupled and now strongly rely on each other.

Therefore, I guess my "objective" question is about the acceptability of each of these. Is keeping the models (database and ORM stuff) and the API routes decoupled better practice than combining them together? What are some of the advantages and disadvantages of doing each of these? What is the most common and recommended practice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You said you are building a very small API, so don't care that. Anything is OK for you, please use ways what you feel most comfortable and fast.

Comment: @YangHG I have to disagree. Actually, I couldn't disagree more...

Comment: To whoever voted to close this as "primarily opinion-based": separating domain logic from presentation / UI (actually and more generally "separation of concerns") is not "opinion based", it's a long-established good practice derived from both logical reasons and actual experience.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: it's fine to put a function within the model class however if you want secure logins you will need to pass the login information within a token using something like [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class) (I'm not sure what the equivalent extension is for django).

Putting a function within the class is fine, however this won't be very secure for a login, so I'd suggest following a tutorial for implementing a secure login extention.

For example, on one of my projects the views function for the login page is:

```
@user.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm(next=request.args.get('next'))

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        u = User.find_by_identity(request.form.get('identity'))

        if u and u.authenticated(password=request.form.get('password')):
            if login_user(u, remember=True) and u.is_active():
                # Handle optionally redirecting to the next URL safely.
                next_url = request.form.get('next')
                if next_url:
                    return redirect(safe_next_url(next_url))
                return redirect(url_for('user.settings'))
        else:
            flash('Identity or password is incorrect.', 'error')

return render_template('user/login.html', form=form)
```

Note that the `u.authenticated` is a function within my User model Class that checks the users password hash is correct:

```
    def authenticated(self, with_password=True, password=''):

    #Ensure a user is authenticated, and optionally check their password.
    if with_password:
        return check_password_hash(self.password, password)

    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR : your `login` method - which is only about HTTP-related stuff - doesn't belong to the model layer, period.

Longest answer : adding logic to models is of course a good design, but this has to be *domain* logic, not UI-related stuff. The point (since you ask about "good practices") is to keep the domain layer (models) totally independant of the UI (views and controllers) so you can use the same domain layer with different UIs (remember that command-line scripts ARE a UI too).

I had to work with quite a few badly designed applications/frameworks that mixed concerns and actually *required* having a "request" (http request) and "response" object at hand whatever you wanted to do and those were a complete nightmare to deal with, so from experience the "separation of concerns" rule is not something you want to break.

Just note that this doesn't mean the UI layer should not know about the domain - this would make no sense, and would actually be just impossible from a technical POV.